# Possible to copy/paste column easily?

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, text-editors, text-editing

Take a page like the following - [en.wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history)

I want to copy and paste all of the android version names into one list (so I can insert it as a synonym list to pass into a classifier).

What is the *easiest* way I can do this? I know I could copy/paste into Excel or some such program and do some clever manipulation - but I'm sure there is some really simple way to accomplish tasks like this. You can't hold ctrl and highlight just the relevant areas....but there must be some similarly simple solution, is there?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Select the table, copy to Excel, select first column and copy to your tool. Doesn't work for you? Isn't easy enough?

Comment: @MátéJuhász My issue is that this is a really common task - for me anyway. The approach you take is simple enough, but requires probably....20 clicks? I'm thinking/hoping there may be a way to streamline the process :).

Comment: Program it in... You can read from the website in VBa and then extract the information. However, not sure if you having to program is considered `easy` or not ...

Comment: It's only 14 versions. Before you can cleverly think of a way, you could have typed them in already. However you could copy, paste into a text file on Desktop, import data with 'tab' or maybe 'space' as a delimiter, but by then... Makes sense for a hundred or a thousand lines of data.

Comment: Let's imagine a tool perfectly fitting your need would exist; you still need to: navigate to the webpage, select the table you need the data from, start / call the tool, specify which column you need, copy it to your final tool. Doesn't seems much shorter then working through Excel.